# Clean up large block of plain text - find and replace plain text

Tags: jquery

I have a huge chunk of text (thousands of lines) that needs to be cleaned up a bit. I have 2 values, "date", and "title". Currently, the "title" holds a sentence and a number. The number starts with "no." and has the date plus a few random characters. I would like to have "date", "title", and "no". The "title" would no longer include the "no. xxxxx" characters.

So the text currently looks like this:

```
"date": "02/01/2012",
"title": "my sample title no. 02012012-abc",

"date": "02/01/2012",
"title": "my sample title is always different and varies in character length    no. 02012012-cde",

"date": "02/01/2012",
"title": "my sample title is always different and varies in character length    no. 02012012-ghe",

"date": "02/01/2012",
"title": "my sample title is always different and varies in character length    no. 02012012-zxa"
```

I would like to clean up the data to look like this:

```
"date": "02/01/2012",
"title": "my sample title",
"no.": "02012012-abc",

"date": "02/01/2012",
"title": "my sample title is always different and varies in character length",
"no.": "02012012-cde",

"date": "02/01/2012",
"title": "my sample title is always different and varies in character length",
"no.": "02012012-ghe",

"date": "02/01/2012",
"title": "my sample title is always different and varies in character length",
"no.": "02012012-zxa"
```

Comment: What have you tried? Does this _need_ to be in code, or is it a one-off which could be done using Notepad++ (or similar)?

Comment: @DaveSalomon I'm working on a jQuery snippet. It can be done in anything but my initial thought was jQuery. I know for a fact the "no." characters always have 8 numbers followed by a dash followed by 3 letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you just use regex to replace `/no./g` with `\nno.`